# What does TimeZone.getTimeZone().getRawOffset() depends on?

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

When I run this code on *ideone*: https://ideone.com/sm2SHC I receive `10800000` in stdout, when I run it locally I can see `7200000`.

The code that produces this output is:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Khartoum").getRawOffset());
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. The idea is that questions are self-contained because external links will eventually go dead. Provide a [mcve] along with an explanation what you are trying to do, and what results you get. In general, you should also show your research. What have you done to solve your problem?

Comment: The `TimeZone` class is long outdated, only one of the outdated date and time classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1. Today it is recommended that instead you use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its classes `ZoneId` and `ZoneRules`.

Answer (score 1):

The `getRawOffset` method, [as described in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getRawOffset--), returns the raw offset value (without DST if applicable) of the *current* date, in terms of milliseconds.  Divide by 3600000 to get to hours, and you'll see the values you reported are UTC+3 in IDEOne and UTC+2 in your local environment.

If we look at the the underlying [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) entry [for this time zone](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2018e/africa#L1160-L1163), we see the following:

```
# Zone  NAME            GMTOFF   RULES  FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone    Africa/Khartoum 2:10:08  -      LMT     1931
                        2:00     Sudan  CA%sT   2000 Jan 15 12:00
                        3:00     -      EAT     2017 Nov  1
                        2:00     -      CAT
```

The last two entries show that UTC+3 was in effect until 1 Nov 2017, at which time Khartoum switched to UTC+2.  Dig deep enough and you'll find this change was made in version `2017c`, and is included in [the release announcement here](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2017-October/000047.html).

Java ships TZDB updates with each JRE release (and via a separate out-of-band process called [TZUpdater](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html)). We can [update your IDEOne](https://ideone.com/Ytsoqz) to see what versions of TZDB and JRE are running there.

```
System.out.println(java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getVersions("UTC").keySet());
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));

// outputs [2016f] and 1.8.0_112
```

Indeed, we can see in [Oracle's list of time zone versions in JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html), that 2016f first shipped with 8u111, and the next in-band release was with 8u121 for 2016i.  [The Wikipedia page on Java Updates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8_updates) confirms Java 8 update 112 came out on 2016-10-18.

Since Khartoum had not moved to UTC+2 yet, then the older version of Java simply doesn't have that information.  IDEOne would need to update either their JRE version, or run [TZUpdater](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html), to carry the more current information.

Likely your local environment is on a newer update of Java, which has 2017c or higher time zone data.

Also, modern Java should no longer use `java.util.TimeZone`, but rather should prefer the [improved java.time APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) instead.  Using these APIs, you probably won't need to work with a raw offset value directly.